# How to solve insert/delete deadlock on non-clustered index?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I got a deadlock problem and I found that it's caused by two stored procedures that is called by different threads (2 called web services).

1. **Insert sp** that insert data in X table.
2. **Delete sp** that delete data in X table.

Moreover, I got result that told me about deadlock happened in non-unique and non-clustered index of X table. Do you have any idea for solve this problem?

**Update**

From [Read/Write deadlock](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/16/readwrite-deadlock/), I think it error because of the following statements.

- In insert statement, it get id(clustered index) and then non-clustered index.
- In delete statment, it get non-clustered index before id.

So, I need to select id for delete statment like the following statement.

```
SELECT id FROM X WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE [condition]
```

PS. Both stored procedures are called in transaction.

**Thanks,**

Comment: Can you post the deadlock info?

Comment: I can't. I only know above content that I posted. Some people in tester teams only give me little infomation.

Comment: Although is me I pointed you to the read-write article, I have to worn not to jump to conclusion to early. The INSERT will insert a *new* record, so it cannot conflict so easily. There has to be more at play. Maybe some left over info in the ERRORLOG? E repro with profiler attached and deadlock graph captured?

Answer (score 4):

We'd have to see some kind of code... you mention a transaction; what isolation level is it at? One thing to try is adding the `(UPDLOCK)` hint to any query that you use to find the row (or check existence); so you'll take out a write lock (rather than a read lock) from the start.

When contested, this should then cause (very brief) blocking rather than a deadlock.

Comment: I had two concurrent delete statements on the same table (DELETE FROM blah WHERE id=unique to each thread) both required a clustered index keylock, it was solved by either making the column non clustered OR by calling DELETE FROM blah WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE id=N). Obviously the hint tells them to get that write lock instead of the read lock. I am however completely baffled as to why this is the job of the application programmer and isn't transparent!

Comment: @DrGiles that *is* odd; normally you'd use the `UPDLOCK` on an earlier `SELECT`. The delete itself I would have expected to issue as an update lock automatically. Maybe it relates to the key-range lock behaviour; are you in serializable isolation level?

Comment: @Marc Gravell Tell me about it. The script calls READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON, and doesn't configure ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION, and it appears to be off. I will try to remember to update you all if I figure out what was wrong (wrong ODBC call or SQL config!) as it would be generally good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Do the stored procedures modify anything, or just do reads? If the modify something, are there where clauses on the updates to that they're sufficiently granular? If you can try to update the rows in smaller batches, SQL Server is less likely to deadlock, since it will only lock small amounts of the index, instead of the index as a whole.

If it's possible, can you post the code here that's deadlocking? IF the stored procedures are too long, can you post the offending statements within them (if you know which they are)?

Comment: one sp only insert data in X table and another sp only delete data in X table. But both of sp have some unrelated queries that call other tables.

Comment: Is it possible that these two rows could be attempting to affect the same rows (ie one updates a key value while another attempts to delete it)? If not, you can use query hints to prevent the row-level locks from escalating to higher level page- and table-level locks.

Answer (score 0):

Without the deadlock info is more of a guess than a proper answer... Could be an index access order issue similar to the [read-write deadlock](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/16/readwrite-deadlock/).

Comment: invalid link. Please remove tp//

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the select queries are the actual problem, especially if they are the same tables in both stored procedures, but in a different order. It's important to remember that reading from a table will create (shared) locks. You might want to read up on [lock types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039%28SQL.80%29.aspx).

The same can happen at the index level, as Remus posted about. [The article](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/16/readwrite-deadlock/) he linked offers a good explanation, but unfortunately no one hit wonder solution, because there isn't a single best solution for each case.

I'm not exactly an expert in this field myself really, but using [lock hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213026%28SQL.80%29.aspx), you may be able to ensure the same resources get locked in the same order, preventing a deadlock. You will probably need more information from your testers to effectively solve this though.

Answer (score 0):

The quick way to get your application back doing what it's supposed to is to detect the deadlock error (1205) and rerun the transaction. Code for this can be found in the "TRY...CATCH" section of Books Online.

If you're deleting and inserting, then that's affecting the clustered index, and every non-clustered index on the table also needs to have an insert/delete. So it's definitely very possible for deadlocks to occur. I would start by looking at what your clustered indexes are - try having a surrogate key for your clustered index, for example.

Unfortunately it's almost impossible to completely solve your deadlock problem without more information.

Rob